# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): {(intermediate value)}.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an Expense Listing App using Reactjs.

In this, there is a small part where I created a button to **delete** an expense from the list which is making an **API** call to the server with a request to delete that expense from the **database**, also in frontend.

But the problem here is, when the function `filter()` is called ( see below ), It shows this on the page when clicking the button for deletion, **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): {(intermediate value)}.filter is not a function** ... ( but expense deleted from **DB** and also filter out at **frontend** after refreshing the page ).

Code :

```
 async remove(id){
      await fetch(`/api/expenses/${id}`, {              
        method : 'DELETE',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(() => {
          let updatedExpenses = {...this.state.Expenses}.filter( i => i.id !== id);
          this.setState({Expenses : updatedExpenses});

      });
  }
```

I did not find any problem with the `filter()` **method**

Why It is showing **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): {(intermediate value)}.filter is not a function**, on every time `remove(id)` is called.

Comment: Because `filter` is a method found on arrays, not objects. (arrays are objects too, it's true, but the object spread syntax will never produce an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert `object` into an `array` first and then use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on that array; maybe with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values); here is a example

```js
let filteredValues = Object.values(this.state.Expenses).filter( i => i.id !== id);
```

---

EDIT: the problem was simpler than that and probably was result of typo; you don't any of these you can simply do:

```js
let updatedExpenses = this.state.Expenses.filter( i => i.id !== id)
```

by the way the error was in wrong use of spread syntax; where you wrap it with object instead of an array like this `[...this.state.Expenses]` which will create a copy of `Expenses` array; but its redundant since `.filter()` will return new array.

Comment: But It is already declared as an array. here it is : -- this.state = { Expenses : []  }

Comment: Thank you, It just resolved by changing  `{...this.state.Expenses}.filter(...)`
 with   `  Object.values(this.state.Expenses).filter(...)`